# Why does Persona require I do assertion verification on the server?

Tags: browserid

[Persona's quick setup guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Persona/Quick_Setup) says that I need to verify the assertion from the server:

> It’s extremely important that you verify the assertion on your server, and not in JavaScript running on the user’s browser, since that would be easy to forge.

Although I have already implemented it, why do I need to do it on the server? I anyway need to send the assertion to Persona's own server here: `https://verifier.login.persona.org/verify`

I just want to know what are the security issues if I send the assertion directly from the browser?
What can be spoofed using the browser, and why can't the same data be spoofed when sending  it over my own server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't so much that you're sending the assertion directly from the browser to the verification service, but rather about what happens right after that.

If the **server** is the one performing the verification (by sending it to `verifier.login.persona.org`) then it knows that the assertion is valid because it checked itself. A hostile user cannot intercept and tamper with the communication between the server and the verification service. So the server can create a session for the user and set a cookie. That's all good.

On the other hand, if the **client** is doing the verification, then how is the session created? Perhaps the client code checks that the assertion is valid and then calls `/create_session` on the server? The problem here is that the server needs to trust that when the client asks for a session to be created, it has actually done the check.

Client code running in a user's browser cannot be trusted because it can easily be changed (e.g. using the developer tools) by users. So while you're sending me JavaScript code that properly checks assertions, I could modify that check to skip the assertion check and just lie to your server when asking for a new session to be created.

Comment: Thanks... I realized it after some time after asking the question when completing my implementation of login on the server!